# How to use arrayList sort and manipulate the vlaue

Tags: java, arrays, list, sorting, arraylist

By using Java 11, I am trying to find the average value inside the ArrayList. The algorithm i want to develop is  ((value inside list/maximum value)*100)/length of list). I got number format runtime error while I run the program.
java.lang.NumberFormatException is the error i got.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int N = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine()," ");
        double[] grades = new double[N];
        
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
            grades[i] = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
        }
        
        double sum = 0;
        Arrays.sort(grades);
        
        for(int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++){
            sum += (grades[i]/grades[grades.length-1])*100;
        }
        System.out.println(sum/grades.length);
       
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jheEa.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Instead, [edit] your question and add the code here.

Comment: Next, please provide the full exception stacktrace along with your question. This will help people to help you better and faster. See [ask].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find two issues with the code above:

1. The parsing of `br.readLine()` to `int` is the line which throws `NumberFormatException`, since `br.readLine()` contains both numbers and spaces (at least). Since the line is NOT a valid number, the parsing fails.

   Example:

   - User enters the following when `br.readLine()` is executed: "1 2 3 4"
   - The next instruction looks like: `int N = Integer.parseInt("1 2 3 4")`
   - The correct number should not contain spaces: "1234"
2. This one is not really a bug, however, you're asking the user to input the numbers again on the second appearance of `br.readLine` here: `new StringTokenizer(br.readLine()," ");`

**Solution**

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

// REMOVE NEXT LINE
// int N = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine()," ");

// Read the number of tokens in the string
// The input "1 2 3 4" on the example above should return 4 tokens
int N = st.countTokens();

double[] grades = new double[N];
```